# How can I dynamically import a peer dependency in a file bundled with webpack?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I am working on a plugin that uses jQuery as a peer dependency. When I try importing this plugin into my main project (that has jQuery already installed) I get the error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in <(plugin's folder)>`. It seems that when I try to dynamically import jQuery (a peer dependency) webpack looks in the plugin's `node_modules` folder when compiling, rather than the root project's `node_modules`, even though it is a peer dependency. How can I get webpack to look in the root project's `node_modules` rather than the plugin's `node_modules`?

Webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",  
            jQuery: "jquery" 
        })
    ],
    watch: true,
    resolve: {
        alias: { jquery: "jQuery" }
    }
};
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want to add JQuery to webpack file?

Comment: because I'm making a jquery plugin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution by adding this to my webpack config's `resolve` option:

```
modules: [
            path.resolve('./node_modules'),
            path.resolve('../node_modules')
        ]
```

Edit: The issue seemed to go away completely once I actually imported the project from npm, whereas before I was using an npm link. The above solution is no longer required.